# how to get multiple records using Dompdf in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, dompdf

i have use dompdf plugin in my laravel 5. when i try to get multiple records from my database i get an error...

FatalErrorException in ProductController.php line 25:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found

in my controller i use

```
 public function pdf()
{   
    $items = Input::all();
    $data['items'] = $items->toArray();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('product.index',$data);
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

and in my view

```
foreach($items as $row)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Since your controller is namespaced when you use `Input::all();` you are refering to the class 'Input' of your namespace, which does not exist.

You need to either escape the class name with a backslash `\Input::all();` either add this line at the top of your controller, just below your `namespace` definition:

```
use Input;
```

Comment: If i add use Input; the error is show like dis                         FatalErrorException in ProductController.php line 26:
Call to a member function toArray() on array

Comment: Because `Input::all()` returns an array. You cannot call methods of arrays, they are not objects!